# If the 10000ft pointer is reading 5 (50000ft) when you are at 10ft how do you get it back to zero

Tags: altimeter

Kollsman altimeters 10000ft pointer adjustment

Comment: @CrossRoads Please don't answer in comments.  If you have an answer, make it an answer.  Comments are for clarification (which this question needs).

Answer (score 1):

Check that nothing is causing suction on the static port system, low pressure will cause a higher altitude reading. If the static system is functioning, then turn the knob counterclockwise to read the correct pressure, it is probably off by quite a bit. If it has the correct pressure, then the altimeter likely needs servicing.

Comment: If the altimeter is showing 50,000' while the aircraft is off, the altimeter is bad. If it only shows 50,000' after the aircraft is started, there is probably a plug in the static system. I would also have them open the alternate static and see if that works, if it does then the static system is plugged, otherwise it's probably time for a new altimeter.